# Can an enzyme be activated without allosteric inhibition or activation?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

Are there ways by which an enzyme may be activated or inhibited by non substrate molecules other than allosteric activation or inhibition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what Phototroph mentioned in their [answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/42686/3340) (competitive and non-competitive inhibition), an enzyme can be activated/inhibited via covalent modification of the protein (post-translational modification) such as phosphorylation by [protein kinases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_kinase) (phosphorylation is the most common modification).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [competitive inhibition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_inhibition) is another form of enzyme inhibition. The inhibitor binds to the active site here, as opposed to allosteric inhibition, where it binds to a secondary site. An example of an inhibitor would be the cyanide ion (CN-), which inhibits Cytochrome C oxidase, preventing electron chain transport and thus ATP production. Note this ion is different from the substrate, oxygen.